# opengl - possibility of a mirroring shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, mirror

Until today, when I wanted to create reflections (a mirror) in `opengl`, I rendered a view into a texture and displayed that texture on the mirroring surface.

What i want to know is, are there any **other methods to create a mirror** in opengl?

And 2. can this be done **lonely in shaders** (e.g. geometry shader) ?

Comment: One other way is to use the stencil buffer: [link](https://open.gl/depthstencils#Planarreflections).

Comment: @Iggy you should promote that to an actual answer since it is the main other answer. If it's a flat mirror, stencil out the visible area, then mirror geometry across the plane of the mirror in your vertex shader. Don't forget that you can use a restricted frustum (which likely won't be a right frustum) for clipping when rendering the mirror stuff.

Comment: Planar reflections are very easy to do with a geometry shader. More complicated reflections will probably require you to draw the scene into a texture. The popular new technique these days is RLR (real-time local reflections); it uses the backbuffer from the previous frame and re-projects it for super cheap but super finicky (the reflection will disappear when viewed from a lot of angles) reflection.

Comment: @ AndonM.Coleman how would i do with the refection with a geometry shader? and is there a way to get a perfect reflection?

Comment: Depending on your needs there is also screen space reflection (SSRR), but it requires additional rendering pass.

Comment: I quite like thinking of mirrors by inverting the scene and masking using the stencil buffer as a specific case of [portal rendering](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Mini-Portal).

Comment: @jozxyqk indeed that's how Duke Nukem 3d did its mirrors twenty-odd years ago (subject to stencilling by means other than a stencil buffer, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no universal way to do that, in any 3D API i know of.
Depending on your case there are several possible techniques with different downsides.

- **Planar reflections:** That's what you are doing already.
  Note that your mirror needs to be flat and you have to clip so anything closer than the mirror ins't rendered into the texture.
- **Good old [cubemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping):** attach a cubemap to each mirror then sample it in the reflection direction. This works for any surface but you will need to render the cubemaps (which can be done only once if you don't care about moving objects being reflected). I don't think you can do this without shaders but only the mirror will need one. Its a very common technique as it's easy do implement, can be dynamic and fairly cheap while being easy to integrate into an existing engine.
- **Screen space ray-marching:** It's what [danny-ruijters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584657/danny-ruijters) suggested. Kind of like [SSAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_space_ambient_occlusion) : for each pixel, sample the depth buffer along the reflection vector until you hit something. This has the advantage to be applicable anywhere (on arbitrary complex surfaces) however it can only reflect stuff that appear on screen which can introduce lots of small artifacts but it's completly dynamic and very simple to implement. Note that you will need an additional pass (or rendering normals into a buffer) to access your scene final color in while computing the reflections. You absolutely need shaders for that, but it's post process so it won't interfere with the scene rendering if that's what you fear.
  [Some modern game engines](http://www.crytek.com/download/fmx2013_c3_art_tech_donzallaz_sousa.pdf) use this to add small details to reflective surfaces without the burden of having to compute/store cubemaps.

They are probably many other ways to render mirrors but these are the tree main one (at least for what i know) ways of doing reflections.

Answer (score 6):

Ray-tracing. You can write a ray-tracer in the fragment shader (every fragment follows a ray). Ray-tracers can perfectly deal with reflection (mirroring) on all kinds of surfaces.

You can find an OpenGL example [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.1.-Ray-tracing-with-OpenGL-Compute-Shaders-(Part-I)) and a WebGL example including mirroring [here](http://people.mozilla.org/~sicking/webgl/ray.html).